# C named pipe does not work with multiprocess

Tags: c, multiprocessing, pipe, named-pipes

I would like to create a named pipe in the parent process and after write a string to it in the child process and finally read this string in the parent process. When run the program I dont get back the prompt like still waiting for end of child process. Why the child process not finished?

**Current output:**

[image: current output]

**Expected output:**

(picture created without multiprocesses)

[image]

My source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
     int pipefd[2]; 
     pid_t cpid;    
     char szoveg[32];   
     int fd, ret;
     char buf[32];

     buf[0]=0;



     cpid = fork();
     if (cpid == -1) {
       perror("fork");
       exit(-1);
     }

     if (cpid == 0) {    
       printf("%d: Child process\n",getpid());
       
       strcpy(buf,"Some text \0");
       printf("%d:write to fifo: %s:%ld\n",getpid(),buf,strlen(buf));
       write(fd,buf,strlen(buf)); 

       exit(0);

     } else {
       printf("%d: Parent process\n",getpid());
       
            ret=mkfifo("FifoName",00666);   
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("mkfifo()");
            exit(-1);
        }

        fd=open("FifoName",O_RDWR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            perror("open() error!");
            exit(-1);
        }


        wait(NULL);   
        ret=read(fd,buf,32); 
        printf("%d:read() Read %d bytes: %s\n",getpid(),ret,buf);

        close(fd);
        
        unlink("FifoName"); 


       exit(0);
     }
}
```

Comment: `fd` is uninitialized. `write(fd,...)` is failing.  You probably meant to write into the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

William Pursell right. The problem was the missing fd=open("FifoName",O_RDWR); line from child process.